# How to customize Android Views(like Buttons, scrollbars ect.)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, photoshop

I am looking for a tutorial how to create my own user interface(like using photoshop before and then use it in the app)?

Do you know some good sites or tuts or blogs ;)?

greetings and thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to be a bit more specific about the type of elements you want to customise, as they are handled differently depending on the element.

For example, Buttons and TextViews draw the background using a 9-Patch image...
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html